# How to remove identical lines from two textfiles?

Tags: text-processing

INPUT (two textfiles):

```
> cat foo.txt 
alpha
beta
delta
>
```

and

```
> cat bar.txt 
gamma
epsilon
beta
>
```

OUTPUT (remove lines that appear in both of the files):

```
> SOMEMAGIC foo.txt < bar.txt > foofixed.txt
> cat foofixed.txt
alpha
delta
>
```

and

```
> SOMEMAGIC bar.txt < foo.txt > barfixed.txt
> cat barfixed.txt
gamma
epsilon
>
```

**Question**: how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `comm` for that, but it needs the input to be sorted.

```
comm -23 <(sort foo.txt) <(sort bar.txt) > foofixed.txt
comm -13 <(sort foo.txt) <(sort bar.txt) > barfixed.txt
```

`-23` means "Show only the lines unique to file 1".

Comment: @PeterBill: "Thanks" on stackexchange = upvote/accept :-)